# Is it possible to detect View click if it is drawn outside of it's parent?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-xml, android-viewgroup

I have a `RelativeLayout` with `clipChildren="false"`. Then I have a `view` inside of it which has `marginTop="-50dp"`.

So 50dp of the `View` inside `RelativeLayout` is actually drawn outside of `RelativeLayout`.

Now the problem is that the 50dp that is outside of `RelativeLayout` is not clickable, since it's outside of it's parent.

Is it possible to detect this click, or am I going to have to find another way to set up the layout?

Comment: a possible way is to get x/y of touch events and if these values are inside the view, fire your method.

Comment: wrap your `RelativeLayout` inside another `RelativeLayout` and perform it's click event

Comment: Why do you need to do "-50dp".You can simply create nested Layouts and your view will be clickable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the answer is simple **no**.

I ended up completely changing my view hierarchy to get the View click working. If anyone has a better answer, please do post it and I will accept yours.